# Does the order that column names, from an ADO recordset, are referenced in VB6 or VBA code impact execution speed?

Tags: vba, vb6, ado

I'm looking to optimize a VB6 program's execution speed.

In one of the (many) Functions within the project I'm reading records from an Access table using ADO and initializing variables declared locally within the Function.

I know that the makeup of the sql expression being used to drive the returned query results can (greatly) impact program execution speed.

Does the order in which column names, from an ADO recordset, are referenced in code have an impact on program execution speed?

For example, if the Access table schema has column names A, B, C, D, E, F, and G:

Does it matter if code references the column names from an ADO recordset out of order? For example G first, then A, B, etc.

From a theoretical standpoint, would program execution speed be faster if code referenced the column names in the order they would appear if I iterated through the fields collection and looked at the field names?

I tried testing execution speed by inserting. `start_time = Now()` `end_time = Now()` and doing a DateDiff between the two in seconds.

That proved inconclusive. I get mixed results based on what other programs are open on the machine.

```
'Init the query expression
sql = "Select * from TDx2019 WHERE [G] = 'TDX2' OR [A] >= 2 ORDER BY [A], [C], [F], [E], [B], [D]"

'Connect
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider = sGlobalProviderJ1
conn.open sGlobalFilePathJ1

'Recordset
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.open sql, conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

'Read the records, init global array variables
Do While Not rs.EOF

    'increment the counter
    IndexCounter = IndexCounter + 1

    'init Entries Found flag
    bolEntriesFound = True

    'G --
    If Not IsNull(rs("G")) Then
        Arr_G(IndexCounter) = rs("G")
    Else
        Arr_G(IndexCounter) = Empty
    End If

    'Increment TDx counter
    If Not IsEmpty(Arr_G(IndexCounter)) Then
        lngTDx2Counter = lngTDx2Counter + 1
    End If

    'A --
    If Not IsNull(rs("A")) Then
        Arr_A(IndexCounter) = rs("A")
    Else
        Arr_A(IndexCounter) = Empty
    End If

    'Increment A2 counter
    If Not IsEmpty(Arr_A(IndexCounter)) Then
        lngA2Counter = lngA2Counter + 1
    End If

    'B --
    If Not IsNull(rs("B")) Then
        Arr_B(IndexCounter) = rs("B")
    Else
        Arr_B(IndexCounter) = Empty
    End If

    'C --
    If Not IsNull(rs("C")) Then
        Arr_C(IndexCounter) = rs("C")
    Else
        Arr_C(IndexCounter) = Empty
    End If

    'D --
    If Not IsNull(rs("D")) Then
        Arr_D(IndexCounter) = rs("D")
    Else
        Arr_D(IndexCounter) = Empty
    End If

    'E --
    If Not IsNull(rs("E")) Then
        Arr_E(IndexCounter) = rs("E")
    Else
        Arr_E(IndexCounter) = Empty
    End If

    'F --
    If Not IsNull(rs("F")) Then
        Arr_F(IndexCounter) = rs("F")
    Else
        Arr_F(IndexCounter) = Empty
    End If

    rs.MoveNext
Loop

'Release object references
Set conn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
```

Does the order in which items in a recordset are referenced in code matter?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the implementation details, it's hard to say for sure. However, I'd be gobsmacked if merely reordering the columns had effect on the speed. The reason is that I typically expect that to read a column, you have to first read a record, and there has to be optimizations within the implementation to make it fast as possible without encouraging you to take up cheap tricks to make it run faster.

IOW, if you have to resort to arranging columns in a certain way, it is telling you that the implementation for the ADODB provider is shoddy.

That said, for both DAO and ADO, it is my understanding that you *can* optimize access to a field by using a field object referenced instead of referencing via the fields.

e.g. in generally the code<sup>1</sup> runs a bit faster:

```
Dim rs As xxx.Recordset
Dim fld As xxx.Field

Set rs = GetMyRecordset(...)
Set fld = rs.Fields("SomeImportantColumn")

Do Until rs.EOF
  DoSomethingWith(fld.Value)
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Also, it's generally faster to use `GetRows`. Of course, it is always faster to just execute a update query than looping and reading the recordset to effect an update on rows. Thus, if you are looping just to update or insert, you should be really looking at using a query instead of doing it the RBAR<sup>2</sup> way.

The reason those methods are faster is because you cut down on the numbers of steps that you need to execute in VBA. The implementations of the recordset are likely written in languages like C/C++, and thus can be executed very fast, but when you loop, it has to transition between the low level language and the walled garden of VBA and that costs something. Thus, `GetRows` should always beat out the equivalent behavior implemented in VBA simply just because there's less of transition between C/C++ and VBA for each step of the execution. Same applies to queries.

---

1. This code contains `xxx` as a placeholder for either `DAO` or `ADODB`. You should always disambiguate, even if you are referencing only one or other. Why guess at which type library object is from?
2. *R*ow-*B*y-*A*gonizing-*R*ow - credits to Jeff Moden for the originating the terms. When it comes to SQL, think in sets, not in rows.

Answer (score 0):

i have found that sql statements in ms access always execute slow. I don't think it uses indexes efficiently. i avoid sql in ms access. open the table up directly and set your index order, seek the start of the list, then iterate thorough the records to the bottom of your scope.  Much faster!